# Open a link on page load inside the app itself using Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to open a web page on index page load in ionic. This is what i have written

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>

window.location = "http://www.google.com/";


   </script>
</head>
<body class="platform-android platform-cordova platform-webview">

</body>
</html>
```

Put this doesn't works. I have already downloaded the inapp browser plugin as described [here](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/) but this doesn't works.

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

Can someone help asap.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To open the webpage using InAppBrowser plugin use:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open("http://www.google.com/", '_system');
```

This will open the webpage in a new window. Make sure you call it after the library has loaded and the application is ready, preferably in $ionicPlatform.ready callback called from your app's run() function or controller.